# Whether MongoDB has logs for each insertion and removal

Tags: mongodb

I am wondering whether mongodb has logs for each insertion and removal? ie. monitoring or backup capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

By default only queries which take longer that slowms are logged. You can log every query whith profiling level 2 however. 
[See here for more details](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#profiling-levels)

Comment: where is the log file located?

Comment: depends on where you  specify
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create an extremely verbose log of writes and reads and all that.

When you go to actually run `mongod` you can define a: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--diaglog param which when set to 1 will log every single write operation including insertion and deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the oplog. It could be what you are looking for.

[docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-oplog-sizing)

[www.briancarpio.com](http://www.briancarpio.com/2012/04/21/mongodb-the-oplog-explain/)

Comment: Providing you HAVE an oplog

Comment: You can turn it on in the config oplog=[0,1,2,3,7]